# How to pass dataset in Classification Learner App of Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, classification, svm

My question is about passing variables (training dataset ,Labels and test variable) as predictors and responses. What I do is that load all 3 in workspace of matlab and start session. But every time I get the error(Described in attached Image) i.e No responses selected ,select response variable.My dataset is as following:

1. faces [ size : 5000 * 10000 (5000 samples ,10000 features)]
2. TrainingLabels [ size :5000 *1]
3. TestVariable [ size :1*10000]

Now what should be **Predictors** and **responses** in my case and how can I use them correctly in order to make classification Learner app work?

[image]
Any Kind help regarding this matter will be highly appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1):** Prepare the data!! If you have ***N*** samples of training data and ***M*** samples of test data, then combine it together to make it ***MxN*** samples. The rows, here, represent each sample and the columns the different types of features detected from a sample.

**Step 2):** Add an extra column at FIRST or LAST of the data (preferably): This column should represent the desired labels for the data. So, now you will have : ***total no.of columns= no.of features + 1***. While importing the data into the Classification Learner App, it is advised to import the data as a TABLE.

**Step 3):** Now, set up the data to be used by the Classification Learner App!! By default, all columns will be selected as predictors. The app will prompt you to select the responses. A response is the one which you added as an extra column (the label). So, change the label-column to make it point as a response.

**Step 4):** Before starting the session, you need to set up the Cross Validation strategy adopted. [ A k-fold validation divides the total ***MxN*** data into k-parts and begins by taking the first part of testing and rest ***k-1*** parts for training. Then, again it takes the second part for testing and rest ***k-1*** parts for training and so on. Finally, average of all the accuracies obtained is taken as final accuracy].

**Step 5):** Start session, select the classifier you want and the hit the training button!!!

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the columns as response that is change it from **predictor** to **response** in "Import as" dropdown.

[image]

Comment: should I choose it from training dataset which is named as Faces?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/14488797_249097982153765_728625461_o.png?oh=07006592154a1e5cd0067cd82aa617f9&oe=57EA273A)

Comment: I selected one **row** as response , it has assumed that  there are 255 classes rather than 2 .I have dataset of only two classes for which I have made training labels  also But _How_ can I inform this to classification Learner ?

Comment: You need to choose correct one. Why your variables does not have name but names like column_1...

Comment: My project is basically for gender classification.I haves 5000 faces of males and females (2500 for males and same for females).I made a .mat file and stored all 5000 in it  ,all named faces ,Then when loaded /imported that data into classification learner it is showing variables names as  : column_1,, etc

Comment: Try to choose use rows as variables in Step 1

Comment: Done ! Step 2 ?